# how to handle two type right swipe gestures

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my project i have created a UIView (red view) and given a swipe gestures(right & left) to it. Its working fine and then i kept a slide out slide bar menu. 
Now i am facing problem. If i swipe left the  red view is going fine. when i swipe right the red view is not going and the side bar menu coming.
How to solve this issue. Please help me.

```
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("animations:"))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
viewSlide.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
var left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("animations:"))
left.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
viewSlide.addGestureRecognizer(left)
```

If my communication is not understand please ask again.

thanks

Comment: You can try define `[lowerPriorityGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:higherPriorityGestureRecognizer];`

Comment: super it works thanks iPhonic u helped a lot

Comment: Please put the complete solution so that it can help others.

Comment: [self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer() .requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeRight)]

Comment: above was the solution